# Versioning with SemVer

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

I need a bit of help/advice with versioning with [SemVer](http://semver.org/).

I'm working on a client's website who has sent several related amends both large and small to his site in a word document (like they always do).

I have a branch based off my master branch for these new amends, and have created commits for each completed amend I have done so far.

The idea was that I would complete all of the amends and then release them in the next release (v2.0.0) because I think all of these changes are related and all of them combined are significant enough to warrant a bump in version number.

The issue I have is that the client wants a few of these amends to be made live immediately, before the release of 2.0.0, so what would the best way of handling this be - would I upload these few completed amends into the existing version and increment the minor number, or would I bump it up to 2.0.0 even though all of the amends aren't complete?

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to versioning, but am trying to learn as best I can by reading and trying to make sense of Semantic Versioning site.

Comment: It really depends on what you like. Version numbers are just arbitrary numbers. They don't mean anything by themselves really.

See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/109103/how-fast-should-a-version-number-increment

Comment: This question really doesn't seem to have anything to do with git. Version numbers have no semantic meaning in git. Git uses commit hashes to track file changes, not version numbers. I think perhaps you really meant to ask about SemVer?

Comment: That's a really good point @Ajedi32, thank you for pointing that out. I guess this question would be more related to SemVer and perhaps be regarded as opinion-based. Ideally what I'd like to do is identify all of these latest amends by an incremented version number. I suppose that now means it'd likely be best for me to release of these changes into 2.0.0...

Comment: @Rik_S Version numbers can be used to convey meaning if you adhere to a standard such as [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/). In this sense, there is a distinct correct way to increment version numbers.

Comment: @Rik_S A standard for incrementing version numbers has a real, practical purpose when you can automatically set up your dependency-management to use whatever is the most recent 2.Y.Z version, while steering clear of API-breaking 3.B.C versions.

Comment: @GoonyanHarir Only update to 2.0.0 if any of the requested changes break functionality that's expected by the users of your code. However, it may not really matter in your case. SemVer is more useful when you're developing an API for other programmers, as opposed to developing an end-user application or website. Do other applications rely on any special behaviors of this website?

Comment: @Cory No other applications rely on any special behaviour. This is a simple version-controlled website and not an API

Comment: IMO, the problem at hand has nothing to do with versioning. I can hardly understand why one needs versions for something deployed directly from branches.  I mean, versions are only needed for "shrink-wrapped" products, that is, software sold in boxes and hence requiring identifiable "versions which had been shipped".  For continuous web-site development it appears that it's simpler to just have branches and tags.

Comment: @GoonyanHarir If this question really *is* about SemVer then I'm not sure I'd really call it "opinion-based", since SemVer has some very specific rules about the way version numbers are handled.

If you did indeed mean to ask about SemVer, consider editing your question to make that more clear. (I've already retagged and changed the title for you.)

Comment: @Cory That's why i said "by themselves". As soon as you use a standard, you give them meaning. But since the OP didn't specify any standards he/she was using, i wanted to point out that versioning has no real meaning on its own.

Comment: @Rik_S Our miscommunication may have arisen from the OP sneaking in a mention of SemVer at the end of the question, where it would be easy to overlook. It's a small bit of text that completely alters the context of the question.

Comment: @Rik_S The OP actually did mention SemVer near the end of his question. (Don't worry, I didn't notice it at first either.)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I will try to structure my question/intentions more clearly in the future...

Comment: Cory & Ajedi32: You're both right. My apologies. With keeping SemVer in mind my comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should always consider these two things:

1. What the real changes are? If there are no visible changes, and/or if there are no major changes underneath, it may be better to avoid to increment the major version number.
2. What the customer should perceive of your changes? Saying version 1.1 or version 2.0 may make some difference in how the changes are perceived.

So if the modifications are limited and/or there are no visible things that have changed, it may make sense to increment the minor only and then wait for all of them to be complete to bump it to 2.0.0.